# Prove that $A$ is diagonalizable and find similar matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, orthogonality

Let $A$ be a matrix $(3x3)$ such that:

$A(1,1,1)^t=(2,2,2)^t$ and $rank(2I + A) \lt rank(2I-A)$

I need to prove that $A$ is an diagonalizable matrix and find all the matrices that are similar to it.

I'm having difficulties solving this, can anyone please tell me what I should do?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure about $A(1,1,1)^t=(2,2,2)^t$? I don't see how an orthogonal matrix can transform a vector into another vector that is twice as long.

Comment: I found the mistake, I should have written that $A$ is diagonalizable not orthogonal.

Answer (score 2):

From the first equality you get that $2$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, so $\operatorname{rank}(2I-A)<3$. Also $\operatorname{rank}(2I+A)<3$, and therefore $-2$ is an eigenvalue as well. The geometric multiplicity of $2$ is thus $1$ or $2$, meaning, respectively, $\operatorname{rank}(2I-A)=2$ and $\operatorname{rank}(2I-A)=1$. The latter is impossible, because it would imply $\operatorname{rank}(2I+A)=0$ and so the geometric multiplicity of $-2$ would be $3$.

Hence $\operatorname{rank}(2I-A)=2$ and $\operatorname{rank}(2I+A)=1$.

Can you go on?

Comment: Hi, I fixed the problem as there was an error there. Can you please tell me how did you know that $rank(2I - A) \lt 3$? I understand why $2$ is an eigenvalue

Comment: @FigureItOut $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of the $n\times n$ matrix $A$ if and only if $\lambda I-A$ is not invertible, that is, it has rank $<n$.

Answer (score 1):

A isn't necessarily orthogonal.

$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}-2&0&4\\0&-2&4\\0&0&2\end{bmatrix}
$$

satisfies your conditions and isn't orthogonal, i.e. its columns aren't orthogonal.

Comment: @FigureItOut Just saw your edit :)